# How to post raw json below in the body of retrofit request?

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit

Here I am using retrofit 1.9 and I have to post this json in post request.

```
{
"note": "",
"amount": "0",
"frequency": null,
"patient": "sameer_998oiib@innotical.com",
"doctor": "",
"date": "2016-04-27",
"reminder": 
[
{
    "days": [2],
    "time": "06:29:00"
}, 
{
    "days": [2, 3],
    "time": "06:30:00"
}
],
"salt": "Abobotulinum Toxin A Injection",
"method": 2,
"unit": 1
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create an Object like

```
public class PostObject{
        String note;
        String amount;
        String frequency;
        String patient;
        String doctor;
        String date;
        String salt;
        int method;
        int unit;
        List<Reminder> reminder;

        class Reminder{
            List<Integer> days;
            String time;
        }

    }
```

and set your request body object

Comment: create a PostObject with your values like : PostObject object = new PostObject(....)

Comment: I have created object of this class but I am unable to assign values to days    and time keys

Comment: then I have to pass reminder class object in postObject parameter?

Comment: you can set like this : object.setReminder(reminder)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112227/discussion-between-linh-nguyen-and-chetanya-arora).